# How to create a dynamic function name?

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am using carbon which add date depending on frequency. Currently this is my working code.

```
if ($repetition_frequency == 'Day') {

   $test_date->addDays($repetition);

} else if ($repetition_frequency == 'Week') {

   $test_date->addWeeks($repetition);

}else if ($repetition_frequency == 'Month') {

   $test_date->addMonths($repetition);

}else if ($repetition_frequency == 'Year') {

   $test_date->addYears($repetition);

}
```

My goal is to remove the if condition and depend what function i will call by $repetition_frequency

**Goal:**

```
ex: $repetition_frequency = 'Year';

$test_date->'add'.$repetition_frequency->($repetition);

// i want => $test_date->addYear->($repetition);
```

I know this won't work. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: `$test_date->{'add'.$repetition_frequency}($repetition)` might work, but you should probably submit it as an argument instead of having dynamic functions. Dynamic variable names and method names can easily lead to issues.

Comment: @Qirel can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `addUnit` method available out of the box:

```
Carbon::now()->addUnit($repetition_frequency, $repetition)
```

It will take indifferently `Day`, `day`, `days` cases/pluralization and any supported unit of Carbon.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a dynamic function name. Such code is difficult to understand. Just do it like this:

```
$test_date = Carbon\Carbon::today();  //2020-06-10

$repetition = 3;
$repetition_frequency = 'Year';

$test_date->modify($repetition." ".$repetition_frequency);

echo (string)$test_date;
```

Output:

```
2023-06-10 00:00:00
```

Instead of "Year" it also works with Day, Week, Month etc. ([see units relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php))
You don't even need Carbon for that, DateTime does it well.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but you either need to catch it in a variable or use {} to separate the code

```
ex: $repetition_frequency = 'Year';

$function = 'add'.$repetition_frequency;

$test_date->$function($repetition);
```

Also be wary of the out of the box date addition functions like modify and addMonths, if you were to add 1 month to 2020-01-31 you would end up with 2020-03-03, which may not be your desired result.  Carbon comes with a handy `addMonthNoOverflow` function if the desired result should be 2020-02-29.

Comment: Just because he can, doesn't mean he should. @jspit's answer is much better.

Comment: In this use case maybe, understanding how a language works and what is possible for other cases is valuable knowledge.